# Clearing jQuery Dialog validate upon open

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui

I am encountering similar behaviour in my code: https://codepen.io/iw3/pen/BAdIq

html

```
<input id="open" type="button" value="Open" />
<div id="dialog">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="field" />
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
  $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      'Send': function() {
        if ($('#form').valid()) {
          alert('Success');
          $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $('#open').on('click', function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
  });
  $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      field: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        maxlength: 9,
        min: 1
      }
    }
  });
});
```

When the user enters data in the form and gets an error, then closes the form and reopens it, the validate messages in red remain while they should really be cleared. Is this an intended behavior or is there a way to reset the validate?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you can simply hide the validation error `label` elements when the dialog is closed:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  close: function() {
    $('label.error').hide();
  },
  // other configuration settings...
});
```

Alternatively you can save a reference to the `validator` and call `resetForm()` on it when the dialog is closed:

```
let validator = $('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    // your rules...
  }
});

$('#dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  close: function() {
    validator.resetForm();
  },
  // other configuration settings...
});
```